# Using Datetime to print a couple of days into the future

Tags: python, datetime

I want to have the date show the current date, and then get the next 15 days. Im having an error somewhere and I cant figure it out.

```
from datetime import datetime

dated = datetime.now()
for i in range(15): 
    dated += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    print(dated)
```

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should import `timedelta`:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

dated = datetime.now()
for i in range(15): 
    dated += timedelta(days=1)
    print(dated)
```

or the whole module `datetime`

```
import datetime

dated = datetime.datetime.now()
for i in range(15): 
    dated += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    print(dated)
```

Comment: I think they also don't want to be reassigning dated, maybe it should be `dated_day = dated + time_delta(days=i)` in the loop.

Comment: Just kidding I didn't realize they were adding one day at a time.